# Black stuff on the underside of leaf on a lemon tree

Tags: leaves, fungus, citrus, lemons

I'm trying to identify what is wrong with my lemon tree.

Previously it had aphids and I treated that and they're gone, but now it has some black stuff on the underside of the leafs and is causing them to fall off.

Here's some photos:

[image]

[image]

Comment: To make better photos I suggest to cut off a leaf (or a part of it) and attach it to a sheet of paper. Then you can control light and focus.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the photos, but perhaps a fungus called [black sooty mold](https://gardendownsouth.com/how-to-remove-black-sooty-mold/#:%7E:text=Black%20sooty%20mold%20is%20actually%20an%20airborne%20fungi,excrete%20a%20thick%20gooey%20sugary%20substance%20called%20honeydew.)

> **What Causes Black Sooty Mold?**
>
> Black sooty mold is actually an airborne fungi spore that latches on
> to the sweet sticky honeydew secreted by leaf and bark feeding
> insects.
>
> On Crepe Myrtles and most other plants the culprit here is either sap
> sucking Aphids or Bark sucking Scale.

[This](http://dianestexasgarden.blogspot.com/2010/08/lemon-tree-fungus.html) is how it looks like on a lemon tree.